# Find elements of array that contains a specific value

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have such schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55de668b4ac1fc9e75552db0"),
    "name" : "john",
    "documents" : {
        "number" : "125",
        "_clas" : "some class type here"
    }
}
```

How can I find all persons that have "pay" as their documents class type?
I need output like

```
john, 125
john, 456
Ann, 234
Ivan, 345
```

but elements with _class = "qwe" should not be in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to filter your documents with _class as "pay", then you can do a simple find query,

```
db.collection.find({
  "documents._clas": "pay"
})
```

If you also want the response to be structured the way you've given, then you'll have to use an aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "documents._clas": "pay"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "product": "$documents._clas"
    }
  }
])
```

The $match stage finds documents that match the query you require (_class as 'pay') and the $project stage gets the output in the required format.

EDIT:
Considering documents to be an array, the solution would be

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "documents._clas": "pay"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "product": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$documents",
          as: "document",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$document._clas",
              "pay"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The match stage gets documents which have pay as any one of the array elements, if you think all the documents in the collection will have at least one pay _clas, then you can skip that stage.

Comment: No, thats not give valid results:
<code>"_id" : "eb38cd12-1a5c-46ce-ad4c-e736d8cb0bf9",
    "name" : "john",
    "product" : [ 
        "pay", 
        "given", 
        "given", 
        "pay", 
        "help"
    ]<code>
But I need only
<code>"_id" : "eb38cd12-1a5c-46ce-ad4c-e736d8cb0bf9",
    "name" : "john",
    "product" : [ 
        "pay", 
        "pay"
    ]<code>

Comment: Is the _clas field an array?
can you put up some documents from your collection and the exact response you're expecting ?

Comment: Your code returns documents, that have at least one element at "documents" array where "_clas" : "pay" and it returns all of "documents" array too but I need only where "_clas" is "pay", not all elements

Comment: So documents is an array ? 
In the question, it is an object

Comment: Yea, it very near to good answer. Now I use script very like yours:
[ {$project:{ internalNum:1, pay:{$size:{ $filter: { input: '$documents', as: 'item', cond: { $eq: [ '$$item._class', 'DocumentPayment' ] } } }},
                pay2:{ $filter: { input: '$documents', as: 'item', cond: { $eq: [ '$$item._class', 'DocumentPayment' ] } } } }},{$match:{pay:{$gt:9}}},{ $project: { internalNum:1, pay2: 1 } } ]
but how to get accsess to pay2[0].name or pay2[1].name fields? I need all pay2[].name fields

Comment: Thanx a lot!
I have find solvation